# C# webapi send data after Return

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an API that returns a list of shops from my database along with shops from Google Places API.

```
 IEnumerable<ShopInOfferDetails> modelApi = null;
 IEnumerable<ShopInOfferDetails> modelDb = null;

            await new TaskFactory()
                .StartNew(() =>
                {
                    modelApi = Service.GetShopsFromGoogleApi(g);

                })
                .ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    modelDb = Service.GetShopsFromDb(g);
                });


var model = modelApi.Concat(modelDb);    
return model;
```

The thing is that it takes too long to get and process the results from Google API (I am doing some more work at the background) and I wonder if there is a way to get the first data from my database - to return this data to the client and only then to get more data from Google Api and Return again - in such way the client gets the first result fast and then the rest from Google API.

Comment: Both your calls do IO. One for the DB and one for Google. I'd suggest invoking them concurrently by using their naturally async API's, such are offered via `HttpClient` and many ORMs. Then you could `await Task.WhenAll` on both. Alternatively, @Damir's suggestion for creating two different calls may also work if you want to show the end user a result ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would create 2 different web API methods and call both of them asynchronously from the client. When each one of them returns, the client can immediately show the results - this would create the desired effect: the user would first see the results from the database and then the slower ones from Google API.

Comment: I was thinking about this option  but I would like to control the number of the results - If I get enough from my database I won't return from Google. If I won't find the solution that what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor this a bit:

```
List<ShopInOfferDetails> items = new List<ShopInOfferDetails>();

List<Task<IEnumerable<ShopInOfferDetails>>> tasks = new List<Task<IEnumerable<ShopInOfferDetails>>>();
var task1 = Task.Run(() => {
    items.AddRange(Service.GetShopsFromGoogleApi(g));
    });
tasks.Add(task1);
var task2 = Task.Run(() => {
    items.AddRange(Service.GetShopsFromDb(g));
    });
tasks.Add(task2);

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

return items;
```